# WebApi OAuth UseOAuthBearerAuthentication gives "Sequence contains more than one element" error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin, bearer-token

I configured my WebApi OAuth 2.0 by these lines:

```
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider(),
    });

    app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
```

But it gives me the following error at each request :

```
Message : An error has occurred.
ExceptionMessage : Sequence contains more than one element
ExceptionType : System.InvalidOperationException
StackTrace :    at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationManager.d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Web.Http.HostAuthenticationFilter.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()
```

My `OAuthOptions` is :

```
    OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
        Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
        AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/Account/ExternalLogin"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
    };
}
```

If I comment **UseOAuthBearerAuthentication** everything is ok! I didn't customize OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider yet and I use it directly but why does it give me error?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It should be a bug! Use

`app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);`

instead of

`app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);`

Comment: You are a light-saber

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue. This was working for me but now it does not work any more. I did find some threads that suggested possible cause is Owin version updrage from 3.0.0 to 3.0.1. However even if I registered 3.0.0 it does not work for me. Tried the above solution still it does not work. Could any one guide here?

Comment: Ask your question in a new thread. No one can see your question here!

Comment: you are great i pull my hair last 1 day you make my day

Comment: @MahmoudMoravej - Ok this cost me about a day... can someone explain why does this work?

Comment: This saved my finding time.

Comment: If someone came here because of two-factor authentication so what solved my issue was just to delete all the bin folder. Like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986909/a-route-named-x-is-already-in-the-route-collection-route-names-must-be-unique

Comment: I faced the similar issue in one of our project, It took sometime to solve, but I find out  that UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication was used twice. Removing one solved my problem