# Sequence contains more than one element Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationManager

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, owin, google-authentication

While trying to authenticate externally using Google, application gives me following exception:

> <Error>
>   <Message>An error has occurred.
>   <ExceptionMessage>Sequence contains more than one element</ExceptionMessage>
>   <ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
>   <StackTrace>
>       at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationManager.<AuthenticateAsync>d__8.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Web.Http.HostAuthenticationFilter.d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() at System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()

I have configured my Web Api oAuth as follows:

```
public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(
        Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();

    OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = 
        new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
    {
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
        Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(),
    };

    app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);

    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);

    googleAuthOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
    {
        ClientId = ClientId,
        ClientSecret = ClientSecret,
        Provider = new GoogleAuthProvider()
    };

    app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleAuthOptions);
}
```

Comment: i found solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978940/webapi-oauth-useoauthbearerauthentication-gives-sequence-contains-more-than-one) it will help you

Answer (score 8):

Check, please, may be you use 
`app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);` 
and 
`app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());` together

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by using the following two configuration settings together (I was using refresh tokens):

```
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
```

Answer (score 2):

I also got this error, and it turned out I had the following:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie}
```

in my SecurityConfig
but also this on a Controller:

```
[HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)]
```

(For completeness sake: I used web.api owin only, using owin IIS hosting)

**Solution:** Removing one of these fixed the issue, so I guess adding a controller attribute like this, is the same as configuring twice. Look for suspicious things like this (they also might be configured in a library that you use!)

Some further background info about where the error occurs:

In my case it was observed that lots of times (but not always ?!) the error occurs. Debugging learned that the offending method lives in Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationManager:

```
public async Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateAsync(string authenticationType)
{
  IEnumerable<AuthenticateResult> source = await this.AuthenticateAsync(new string[] { authenticationType });
  return source.SingleOrDefault<AuthenticateResult>(); //<== this line throws because there are two  
}
```

(authenticationType was "ExternalCookie" in my case)

Answer (score 1):

see [WebApi OAuth UseOAuthBearerAuthentication gives "Sequence contains more than one element" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978940/webapi-oauth-useoauthbearerauthentication-gives-sequence-contains-more-than-one).  I myself fixed it by commenting out

```
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);
```

instead, but i guess they aren't compatible to have both at the same time?