# A route named 'MS_attributerouteWebApi' is already in the route collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I recently added `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost` to a MVC WebAPI project which would allow me to use the `[Route("api/some-action")]` attribute on my action. I solved some errors using [this article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) but can't solve the third error below. Added solved errors below to get feedback if I did anything wrong.

**First Error**: No action was found on the controller 'X' that matches the name 'some-action'

**Solution**: Added `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` to WebApiConfig.cs `Register` method.

**Second Error**: System.InvalidOperationException The object has not yet been initialized. Ensure that HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized() is called in the application's startup code after all other initialization code.

**Solution**: Added `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);` to Global.asax.cs `Application_Start`

**Third Error**: System.ArgumentException: A route named 'MS_attributerouteWebApi' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique.

**Solution** = ?

I've already tried cleaning and deleting all DLLs from bin folder according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986909/a-route-named-x-is-already-in-the-route-collection-route-names-must-be-unique).

Answer (score 45):

I had a similar problem and it was related to a copy paste error on my part where I added a copy of this line in my WebApiConfig.cs file:

> config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

make sure you only have one of these.

Comment: or like me duplication was in  Global.asax.cs with GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config => config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes())

Answer (score 19):

In the **Global.asax**, check how many times `WebApiConfig.Register` function has been called.

Answer (score 7):

Solved! Removed the line `WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);` from Global.asax.cs `Application_Start`.

Comment: GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); was the first line in my global.asax and it seems to be doing the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

I have solved by cleaning the deployment directory before copy the new files. Probably there was some old file that try to register the same root multiple times.

Comment: I had rogue DLLs in my bin folder after a project rename.  Cleaning the project didn't help, so I had to delete the DLLs manually through Explorer

Comment: I really hate this kind of solution, but in this case. works.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and I discovered that in WebApiConfig.cs
and after I added configuration for API version

I have those two lines

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(constraintResolver);

config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

I removed the second line

the final code is

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        // Web API routes
        var constraintResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver()
        {
            ConstraintMap =
            {
                ["apiVersion"] = typeof( ApiVersionRouteConstraint )
            }
        };
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(constraintResolver);
        config.AddApiVersioning();

        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
       // config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For anybody stumbling across this as I did, this error will happen if you rename the Assembly name (project properties). In my case I was renaming a project, and went into the properties to change the assembly name (which VS2013 won't do for you).

Because the assembly name is different, a Clean or Rebuild will not remove the "old" assembly if it is in the \bin folder. You have to delete the assembly from the \bin folder, then rebuild & run.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have same register more than one.

Try to  delete below codes from Global.asax:

> ```
> GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
>   RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
> ```

and write this ones instead of them :

> GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();
>       BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

I am not sure about reason; but it worked for me in my same case.

Answer (score 0):

I was also experiencing a similar problem (not the `MS_attributerouteWebApi` route in particular, but a different named route). After verifying only one `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()` existed, began realizing that `MapHttpAttributeRoutes` will register all project assemblies including externally referenced ones.  After finding out that I had a referenced assembly that was registering its own routes, I found a way to exclude or "skip over" routes by overriding the `DefaultDirectRouteProvider`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Allows for exclusion from attribute routing of controllers based on name
/// </summary>
public class ExcludeByControllerNameRouteProvider : DefaultDirectRouteProvider {

    private string _exclude;
    /// <summary>
    /// Pass in the string value that you want to exclude, matches on "ControllerType.FullName" and "ControllerType.BaseType.FullName"
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="exclude"></param>
    public ExcludeByControllerNameRouteProvider(string exclude) {
        _exclude = exclude;
    }

    protected override IReadOnlyList<RouteEntry> GetActionDirectRoutes(
    HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
    IReadOnlyList<IDirectRouteFactory> factories,
    IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver)
    {
        var actionRoutes = new List<RouteEntry>();
        var currentController = actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerType;
        if (!currentController.FullName.Contains(_exclude) && !currentController.BaseType.FullName.Contains(_exclude))
        {
            var result = base.GetActionDirectRoutes(actionDescriptor, factories, constraintResolver);
            actionRoutes = new List<RouteEntry>(result);
        }
        return actionRoutes.AsReadOnly();
    }
}
```

This allows for you to pass a Controller name or Base Type name in to exclude in your `WebApiConfig.cs` like:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(new ExcludeByControllerNameRouteProvider("Controller.Name"));
```

Whether or not directly related, hoping this snippet can help!

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem.  The solution I found was that I needed visual basic support for mono.  When I executed "yum install mono-basic" and restarted my computer the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

In my case error was : "A route named 'MS_attributerouteWebApi' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique.
Parameter name: name"

Code was:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();  // this line had issue

            var constraintResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver();
            constraintResolver.ConstraintMap.Add("nonzero", typeof(NonZeroConstraint));
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(constraintResolver);

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Solution : 
I just removed  - `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` 
line from above method and it got resolved.