# Error:A route named 'signalr.hubs' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique. Parameter name: name

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I am getting error in Global.asax on RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(); error is as bellow:

[image]

**Error:A route named 'signalr.hubs' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique. Parameter name: name**

I am using frame work 4.0

My package is as bellow

```
<packages>
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.6.4" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR" version="1.2.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client" version="1.2.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" version="1.2.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS" version="1.2.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin" version="1.2.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb" version="1.2.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

i have install signal r by bellow command

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Version 1.1.3

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client -Version 1.2.2

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Version 1.2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the bin folder of your project, delete all DLL files from there and then do Clean + Rebuild.

Answer is found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11959535/3731444

Comment: But i am using web site not project.

Comment: @osama_1200 Go to the Visual Studio, right-click on your Project name in the Solution Explorer, click the "Open Folder in File Explorer": http://take.ms/8ztQe Then go to the `bin` folder and manually delete all .dll files from there. After that come back to the Visual Studio, press Build - Clean, wait until it finishes, press Build - Rebuild.

Comment: But friend i am using signal r in web site. I am not using project. This is a problem. When i will remove all dll from bin folder the web site will not build.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure you can fix this problem without having access to the project's source files. It looks like the global.asax is referencing to some obsolete DLLs.

Comment: Try to delete all DLLs, then try to rebuild your web site, it will fail, then add back only those DLLs that are needed.

Comment: I have delete all file which is not needed but same error. i have created demo application for signal r can i send my file to you. really i am so tired to solve this issue.