# Host WebAPI to Azure Error : HelpPage_Default

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-web-app-service

Currently I try to host webAPI to Microsoft Azure and it is showing me this error as below, but when I am running it on localhost, it is not showing this error.

[Error in HelpPage_Default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg4d6.png)

Comment: And what has this to do with Xamarin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A route named "x" is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique. Exception with ASP.NET MVC 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986909/a-route-named-x-is-already-in-the-route-collection-route-names-must-be-unique)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, since it's working on your local side, I assumed that you could **clean your solution** and **remove all files under your bin folders**, then rebuild your solution. When deploying your web application via Visual Studio, check "Remove additional files at destination" under "Settings > File Publish Options" as follows to avoid something residue from older versions of your code.

[image]

Also, you could leverage [KUDU](http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/How-to-add-edit-and-remove-files-in-your-azure-webapp-using-the-kudu-service-dashboard/) to compare your deployed web application content with the local version. Delete all files under "D:\home\site\wwwroot" via KUDU, and re-deploy your web application.